# ASUS X555U Touchpad not working

Tags: release-freya, touchpad, asus

I'm testing Freya in live mode but on my Asus X555 laptop the touchpad is not recognized.

I've found some tutorial to install Focaltech driver, anyway if I run xinput list from the command line i don't see any Focaltech emulation mode. It just show Virtual Core XTEST Pointer. How can i fix it?

**Edit 1:**
I've just tried with a persistent USB mode. Installed Focaltech drivers and nothing has changed.

**Edit 2**
This is the output from xinput list

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Microsoft Microsoft(R) Compact Optical Mouse  id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam                     id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

The command `uname -r` returns `3.19.0-39-generic`
And this is the output from `lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 1904 (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 1916 (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 1903 (rev 08)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d2f (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d31 (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d60 (rev 21)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d61 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d3a (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d03 (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d10 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d14 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d15 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d48 (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d21 (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 9d70 (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 9d23 (rev 21)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

**EDIT 3**
I've also tried Ubuntu 15.10 live mode, with this distro the touchpad works as a mouse, no other gestures like 2-finger scrolling. The model name shown by xinput list is `ELAN1000:00 04F3:0401`

Answer (score -1):

Press and hold <kbd>FN</kbd>, press <kbd>F9</kbd>. Release <kbd>FN</kbd>.

Comment: I do not have an FN key, and it is likely that this shortcut is not universal. A more descriptive answer would be more helpful.

Comment: I tried this combination and up near the shutdown button for a while show the sign of touchpad with cross what thats mean??

Comment: @Lame It means that the touchpad has been disabled. I assume the user thought that your touchpad was simply turned off.